# Show tooltip when the user selects item in QML ComboBox

Tags: qt, combobox, qml, tooltip

I want to show the tooltip when the user selects the item in qml Combobox.

````
ComboBox{                    
  textRole:"name"
  ToolTip.text: "textTooltip"
  model: ListModel{
         ListElement {
              name: "name1"
              textTooltip: "tooltip1"
         }
         ListElement {
               name: "name2"
               textTooltip: "tooltip2"
         }

      }
}```
````

Comment: Read more about tooltip visibility and combobox signals.
https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-tooltip.html

Answer (score 1):

you can add a Slot onCurrentIndexChanged of the class ComboBox. When you select an item of model the slot can show the corrett Tooltip.